# VS2019 spectre mitigated libs required?

Tags: c++

I've just installed WDK in my VS2019 installation to compile a simple hello world driver. However I can't seem to do so because I'm receiving an error regarding required spectre libraries `error MSB8040: Spectre-mitigated libraries are required for this project`. I've installed all the required libs (MSVC x64/86 Spectre-mitigated libs) but still get the error and therefore can't compile my driver. I've tried disabling the `QSpectre` flag in the compiler but the error is still thrown. What am I doing wrong?
Screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azABm.png)

Comment: When you change `/QSpectre` you need to rebuild the complete project. Regarding the first part of your question, maybe you just need to restart VS or VS command prompt.

Comment: @S.M. I've rebuilt the project and restarted VS multiple times. I've even restarted my device. Still getting the error

Answer (score 0):

I am answering as I can't comment as this does not qualify as an answer. The only way I see it is to add the components required for spectre mitigation using the visual studio installer-> Individual components.
It is discussed in detail

here 
[To use WDK in VS2019, which Spectre-mitigated library should be installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58811910/to-use-wdk-in-vs2019-which-spectre-mitigated-library-should-be-installed)

and 
here
[How to verify if the Spectre Mitigation flag used in Visual Studio 2017 works for C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51941573/how-to-verify-if-the-spectre-mitigation-flag-used-in-visual-studio-2017-works-fo)